# Usage of hyperref, varioref and cleveref creates bug

Tags: cleveref, ref, varioref

Not really a question, more of a bug I seemed to have found and fixed.
Consider the minimal code below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}   
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
 
\section{Test}
\label{sec:test}

Referencing test section here with ref: \ref{sec:test}, and with cref: \cref{sec:test}.

\end{document}
```

When executed the `\cref{sec:test}` outputs `??`.
To fix it, I removed the varioref package. (Removing hyperref package works as well.)

Does anyone know why this bug occurs, and if it is possible to fix without removing the varioref  or hyperref package?

Comment: works fine for me. Is your system up-to-date? (but I would load varioref before hyperref).

Comment: Works for me with the correct loading order `varioref`+`hyperref`+`cleveref`.

Comment: @campa Is the correct loading order stated somewhere?

Comment: In the `cleveref` documentation, Sec. 14.1.

Comment: Is anyone maintaining this package anymore? I tried to report a bug but the email bounced.

Answer (score 1):

To fix it, remove the varioref package or the hyperref package.

EDIT : As the comments point out, loading in order varioref, hyperref and then cleveref fixes the bug.

Comment: well while loading varioref earlier is recommended, it worked for me also with your order, so check if your system is up-to-date.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Uh, that's interesting; the latest `cleveref` documentation still contains the statement. Since `cleveref` hasn't changed since 2018 I guess something in recent `varioref` and/or `hyperref` updates must have solved whatever issues were behind that.